# How to import VAT in QuickBooks Online UK using API?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I would like to import the order from my website to QuickBooks online UK. The orders needs to import along with the VAT separation. I do not see any way to get this done through API.

Please advice.

Thanks.
Ketan

Answer (score 2):

V3 APIs for QBO will start supporting this: http://ippblog.intuit.com/blog/2013/02/quickbooks-api-v3-webinar-recording.html

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2013, none of the QuickBooks Online APIs that Intuit provides support non-USA versions of QuickBooks.

You can see the Intuit Developers confirming this in the following forum thread:

- https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=69&threadid=18683&enterthread=y

Specifically, one of the developers says:

> At this time there is no estimate on when IPP will be available outside of the US for QBO or QBD.

Thus, because the USA doesn't have VAT, there is no support in the APIs for VAT. Sorry for the bad news!